# js код для яндекс карт не работает в ie8

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Вот смотрите, насочинял такой код.Нажимаете на checkbox и на карте появляются определённые точки. Код работает во всех браузерах, само собой кроме осла ниже 8. И собственно вопрос, можно ли заставить при выборе чекбокса их работать как в других браузерах (так же по умолчанию пытаюсь выставить чекбокся в true что бы были показаны все точки, но тоже не получается)

```
var myMap;
// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
    // заданным id ("map").
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
        // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
        center: [59.96, 30.38],
            zoom: 11,
    });

 var pm1 = new ymaps.Placemark([59.95, 30.32], {
        iconContent: '1',
         balloonContent: '<div class="popupHead">Заголовок</div><br>'+

    },{
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: '/ggg.png',
            iconImageSize: [28, 39],
            iconImageOffset: [-3, -42],
            clusterize: true,

    });

// и так все переменные до  pm69

var myLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '{{ properties.iconContent }}', {
            build: function () {
                var number = 0,
                    geoObjects = this.getData().properties
                        .get('geoObjects');
                for (var i = 0; i < geoObjects.length; i++) {
                    number += parseInt(
                        geoObjects[i].properties
                            .get('iconContent')
                              );
                }
                this.getData().properties.set('iconContent', number.toString());
                myLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
            }
        }
    );
    var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
        clusterIconContentLayout: myLayout
    });
    $('#aa').click(function(){alert('asasa')});
    $('#q1').on("click", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){clusterer.add([pm1,]);}else{clusterer.remove([pm1,]);}
    });
        $('#q2').on("click", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){clusterer.add([pm3,pm4,pm5,pm7,pm8,pm9,pm10,pm11,pm12,pm13,pm14,pm15,pm16,pm17,pm18,pm19,pm20,pm21,pm22,pm23,pm24,pm25,pm26,pm27,pm28,pm29,pm30,pm31,pm32,pm33,pm34,pm35,pm36,pm37,pm38,pm39,pm40,pm41,pm42,pm43,pm44,pm45,pm46,pm47,pm48,pm49,pm50,pm51,pm52,pm53,pm54,pm55,pm56,pm57,pm58,pm59,pm60,pm61,pm62,pm63,pm64,pm65,pm66,pm67,]);}else{clusterer.remove([pm3,pm4,pm5,pm7,pm8,pm9,pm10,pm11,pm12,pm13,pm14,pm15,pm16,pm17,pm18,pm19,pm20,pm21,pm22,pm23,pm24,pm25,pm26,pm27,pm28,pm29,pm30,pm31,pm32,pm33,pm34,pm35,pm36,pm37,pm38,pm39,pm40,pm41,pm42,pm43,pm44,pm45,pm46,pm47,pm48,pm49,pm50,pm51,pm52,pm53,pm54,pm55,pm56,pm57,pm58,pm59,pm60,pm61,pm62,pm63,pm64,pm65,pm66,pm67,]);}
    });
        $('#q3').on("click", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){clusterer.add([pm68,pm69,]);}else{clusterer.remove([pm68,pm69,]);}
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:10px;">
           <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="q1" >группа 1
 <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="q2">группа 2     
 <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="q3">группа 3 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

http://cr65493.tmweb.ru/ - то что не работает

Comment: IE8 мертв!!! Гугл наверное уже и IE10 не поддерживает.

Comment: @Visman ie8 то может и мертв, а вот мой начальник жив, и по этому нужно мастерить костыль, и вот бы хотелось бы что бы подсказали Как?

Comment: А jQuery 1-й мажорности? Из второй версии выпилили поддержку костылей IE.

Comment: Исходя из описания [совместимости API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/versions/concepts/index-docpage/#browsers) с различными браузерами, каких-то серьёзных проблем быть не должно. А у меня мелькнула мысль, что вы подключили версию jQuery 2.x, которая не поддерживается в старых ослах.

Comment: @Deonis в вопросе кинул ссылку